# Sharepoint CSOM - Timeout downloading files

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I'm trying to download files from a large document library (5k+ files) in SharePoint Online. I have a txt file containing the urls for all the files in said library (to avoid the view limits) and download each one using OpenBinaryDirect. The problem is that after a certain number of files (seems to be always the same, around 300 or so), OpenBinaryDirect throws a timeout exception. I'm getting a new instance of ClientContext for each file, and the files are small (less than 100kb). Not sure what's going on, any ideas? I tried changing the file's order to rule out an issue with a particular file but got the same results.

Thanks,

Gonzalo

Comment: have to had any success working around this issue? It appears I'm running into the same issue after a certain time.

Comment: I am also running into the same problem, it apears to happen randomly, especially when downloading various files in a short time.

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is timeout then you should increase the timeout of the clientcontext that you are creating, maybe one file is larger and taking more time to download which exceeds the default timeout.
The below code will set the timeout to 20 minutes.

you can do it by

```
using(ClientContext context=new ClinetContext("http://aboc.come/sites/test"))
{
   context..RequestTimeout= 20 * 60 * 1000;
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee541007.aspx

Comment: Tried setting it to 10 minutes, same results. The files are all very small, less than 300kb.

Comment: are you maintaining a log or something and checking which file is failing ? if so check which file is failing